# How to count number of elements in a doubly-linked list?

Tags: c++

This is how the list is laid out:

```
struct Node {
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    T datum;
};

Node *first;   // points to first Node in list, or 0 if list is empty  
Node *last;    // points to last Node in list, or 0 if list is empty
```

I have tried:

```
int i =0;  
while(first->next)
{  
    i++;  
}
```

but this does not seem right.

Comment: You're testing the same element over and over to see if it's linked to anything. You need to advance the iterator.

Comment: Is this for homework or something? You have a last pointer here... it's not clear if you're expected to stop when you hit that or keep going until next (if you start at first) or prev (if you start at last) is null.

Answer (score 1):

your function needs to loop over the list while updating the pointer to the current node.  Something like this :

```
function getLen(head) {
    var curNode = head;
    var len = 0;

    while (curNode)
        len++;
        curNode = curNode.next;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Comment: You've got an off-by-one there.

Comment: `head` is a pointer type, so you need `curNode->next`, not `curNode.next`.  This pseudocode looks more like Java, where the algorithm is the same but everything is a reference, and there are no value types (other than non-Object types like `int`).  Java uses the same syntax as C/C++ value types, though.  Anyway, not that it's a problem, since it's pseudocode anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by walking a pointer from node to node until the pointer is NULL. Count the number of times the pointer is non-NULL. The code required is very simple:

```
int list_size(const Node *ptr)
{
    int size = 0;
    while (ptr) {
        size++;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    return size;
}
```

Use it like so:

```
int size = list_size(first);
```

This code doesn't use the `prev` pointer so it would also work for a singly-linked list.

Comment: you are updating a const value

Comment: @pwilmot: No, it's a pointer to a `const Node`. The pointer is mutable but what it points to is not. This ensures the function doesn't modify any nodes in the list. If it was declared `Node * const ptr` then the pointer itself would be `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
int i=0;
if(first!=0){
    ++i;
    while(first!=last){
        first=first->next;
        ++i;
    }
}
std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
```